# Asking about number of parellogram in a figure

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, discrete-mathematics

This question was asked by my younger brother and I couldn't solve it.

So, I am asking it here.

Question is ->[image]

I think directly calculating it is a bit lenthy and could lead to error.

Can someone please tell a method for such questions.
I am a masters of mathematics student. So, answer can include proper mathematics techniques.

Comment: it looks like a homework problem?

Comment: @Jyerki menon no it's not. It's competitive exam problem of his class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've divided the parallelograms in two basic types right sided (whose two parallel sides are inclined on right side) and left sided. By symmetry we can say that the no. of parallelograms are equal of each type. So, we will just count the right sided.

1. $1×1$: There are $5$ parallelograms with sides of one unit. $3$ below the middle line and $2$ above.
2. $1×2$: This also includes $5$ parallelograms. $3$ horizontal and $2$ vertical.
3. $1×3$: There is only $1$ parallelogram of these side type which is horizontal below the middle line.
4. $2×2$: It also has $1$ parallelogram.

Hence, it gives us $12$ parallelograms. That means total number of right sided and left sided parallelograms are $24$.

But, there is also a third type which we missed that is neither right nor left. Notice the $3$ three kite shaped parallelograms whose diagonal is the middle line.

So, there are total $27$ parallelograms.

Answer (score 1):

There are 27: 13 made of two triangles, 10 made of four triangles, 2 made of six traingles, 2 made of eight triangles,